# deploying Java app on heroku

Tags: java, web-services, heroku, war, web-deployment

I have made an app which is exposing some REST api's( implemented using Jersey JAX-RS). Now when I  deploy 'war' on heroku, the API's are not accessibe.

I've changed
 http://localhost:8080/myProjectNameInEclipse/webapi/* to -->
http://myAppNameInHeroku.herokuapp.com/myProjectNameInEclipse/webapi/*

but after this the URL's are no longer accessible. Can anybody guide me on renaming URL's while deploying on server (especially on Heroku)

Answer (score 1):

> The web process must listen on one and only one port. The port must be
>   the one specified in the $PORT variable. If your process listens on
>   other ports, it will be shut down by Heroku.

Comment: how can i get this environment variable($PORT) in my js file, and do i need to build URL something like 'myapp.heroku.com:port_env_variable/*'  @Arsenii Andriushchenko

Comment: You can't really change hostname from java, so only port. Which js file? The answer how to get PORT for your JAR is below.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer above. You need a Procfile to indicate the `$PORT` variable

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

[Procfile on heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-a-java-web-application-that-launches-with-jetty-runner#create-a-procfile)